# How to clean docker devicemapper folder properly ?

Tags: docker, device-mapper

I have some problem about the storage. The folder **/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/** is taking 50% of my storage.

In the folder **/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt**, I have many empty folders.

How can I properly clean docker **devicemapper** and remove all unused mapping ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With recent versions of Docker you can see the space used with:

`docker system df`

and prune it with:

`docker system prune`

The above command combines the **prune** command that exists for volumes, containers, images and networks:

`docker volume prune`

`docker container prune`

`docker image prune`

`docker network prune`

Each command has a `--help` option documenting a `-f` (`--force`) option to avoid asking you questions.  It must be used with care.

-o-

On older versions of Docker I ran the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove dead containers (and their volumes)
docker ps -f status=dead --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -r docker rm -v
# Remove dangling volumes
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
# Remove untagged ("<none>") images
docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' | sed -rne 's/([^>]):<none>@/\1@/p' | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove dangling images
docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove temporary files
rm -f /var/lib/docker/tmp/*
```

Comment: Option `-a` can be helpful in `docker image prune -a` for thorough cleanup. Also be it must be used with care.